# How can I get rid of Cocculus Carolinus vine?

Tags: vines, invasive

I would like to know if anyone has successfully eradicated this vine from their yard/flowerbeds. I have just ordered a gallon of Remedy herbicide and am going to attempt to cut the vine near the ground and paint the herbicide on the stem. I have years of growth to deal with as I didn't know what the vine was several years ago when it would have been easier to control. I saw a news article where helium was used to kill Kudzu vine, does anyone know if this would work for killing [Cocculus Carolinas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocculus_carolinus)?

Answer (score 3):

Triclopyr + cut stump = dead infestation.

My lot was covered with Hell Vine (Trumpet Creeper), Virginia Creeper, and Grapevine when I moved in.

Grapevine was easy, Virginia harder because of so many smaller roots, Hell Vine basically roots like a sponge in the ground so I still occasionally get sprouts.

---

Here's my tips:

- Hunt for a big root. If the root you're following disappears underground, you can mark or treat it, or ignore it and go for the daddy roots.
- Don't use a foam brush - the solution will eat through the glue. Even a high-quality foam brush (Jen brand) will lose it's glue. Use a cheap regular brush, crush the metal with pliers for better hold.
- Don't dilute the solution.  You're only applying one or two mL at a time, no need to dilute for cut stump on invasive vines.
- If you want to be super careful (I have in a few instances), then after applying to the root, cover it with a sandwich bag and zip tie it closed
- A plastic cup is fine during the application process, but put the solution back in the bottle or it WILL dissolve the cup. (Found that one out the hard way)
- This stuff is STINKY - nitrile gloves or you'll be stinky too.
- It's a PITA to hunt for and dig up daddy roots, and even more so if you're wearing nitrile gloves and carrying herbicide with you.  I recommend you pick up a $2 bag of marking flags from the hardware store and make it a two part process. Hunt/dig/mark, then cut/apply/secure.
- Apply to both sides of the daddy root, as the daddy root either a) goes to other sprouts, or b) will send up a gang of sprouts when it's cut.  (This applies to any root that goes back underground, actually).
- You'll know in a couple of hours what foliage was affected and what wasn't. You can repeat the process as early as the next day, tracing healthy foliage back to the root.

Good luck.

Comment: This is an excellent answer!

Comment: Thanks. -- Heck, I probably got the initial "how to" from something you posted 2 or 3 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

[This article](https://ask.extension.org/questions/127077) suggests that

> an individual stem treatment with trichlopyr, a 1% solution mixed in
>   diesel or black oil seed. The chemical would be applied to 12 to 18
>   inches of the basal vine stem, making sure that the chemical wraps all
>   the way around the stem (method named basal stem treatment). A
>   registered product that could be used in a lawnscape is readily
>   available and is named "Ortho's Brush-Be-Gone" or "Ortho's Poison-ivy
>   Control". The instructions on the label of these two products should
>   be followed. I am not aware of any chemical that is currently
>   available that can be sprayed on the leaves .